# Error when upgrading to angular 1.2.22

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling

I've upgraded from Angular 1.0.8 to Angular 1.2.22, but I get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$injector/modulerr?p0=gameApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.22%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0Aw%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A443%0Agc%2Fl.%24injector%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A139%0Ac%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A34%3A204%0Ad%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A34%3A418%0Ae%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A327%0Ar%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288%0Ae%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A148%0Agc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A250%0Afc%2Fc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A58%0Afc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A270%0AXc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A359%0A%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A214%3A78%0Aa%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A144%3A390%0Aoe%2Fc%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A31%3A159%0Ar%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288%0Aoe%2Fc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js%3A31%3A143%0A


...p"+(c-1)+"="+encodeURIComponent("function"==typeof arguments[c]?arguments[c].toS...
```

I have no idea what kind of error this is?

Here is my AngularJS code:

```
var gameApp = angular.module("gameApp", []);

gameApp.service('link', function() {
    this.user = false;
});

function makeTableFrom(str) {
    var k = 1;
    result = "";

    for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        result += '<tr>';

        for(var j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
            if(str[k] === '#') {
                result += '<td id=' + k + '">#</td>';
            }
            else if(str[k] === '&') {
                result += '<td class="click" val="water" id="' + k + '">&</td>';
            }
            else {
                result += '<td class="click" id="' + k + '"><a href="#"></a></td>';
            }

            k++;
        }
        result += '</tr>';
    }
    return result;
}


gameApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/firstpage.html',
            controller  : 'firstPageCtrl'
    })

    .when('/game', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/game.html',
            controller  : 'gameCtrl'
    });

});

gameApp.controller("firstPageCtrl", function($scope,$http,link,$location) {
    $scope.doLogin = function() {
        $http.post("lib/action.php", {username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}).success(function(data) {
            if(data) {
                link.user = data;
                console.log(link.user);
                $location.path("/game");
            }
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
});


gameApp.controller("gameCtrl", function($scope,$http,link,$location) {
    //$scope.trr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    //$scope.tdd = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    $scope.getMonsters = "1";
    var map;

    $http.post("lib/action.php", {monsters: $scope.getMonsters}).success(function(data) {
        map = data;
        console.log(map);
        $scope.result = makeTableFrom(data);
        console.log(result);
    });

    if(link.user) {
        /*$scope.message = "fisk";
        console.log(link.user);*/
    } else {
        /*$scope.message = "Ledsen fisk";
        console.log("Är inte satt");*/
    }
});
```

Anyone who can help me to resolve this error? This happens when I upgrade from 1.0.8 to 1.2.22

Comment: Did you not read the changelog? That particular issue is caused by `$routeProvider` not being a part of core any longer, and needs to be included from the file `angular-route.js`. You're jumping two major versions and really should be taking a look at the changelog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll notice the error has a [URL](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=gameApp&p1=%5B$injector:unpr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.22%2F$injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0Aw%2F%3C@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:6:443%0Agc%2Fl.$injector%3C@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:36:139%0Ac@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:34:204%0Ad@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:34:418%0Ae%2F%3C@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:33:327%0Ar@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:7:288%0Ae@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:33:148%0Agc@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:36:250%0Afc%2Fc@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:18:58%0Afc@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:18:270%0AXc@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:17:359%0A@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:214:78%0Aa@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:144:390%0Aoe%2Fc%2F%3C@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:31:159%0Ar@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:7:288%0Aoe%2Fc@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:31:143%0A) in it, which you can click on to get more information.

At version 1.2.0, angular split out its  modules such as `ngRoute`, etc. so that they could be replaced by 3rd party versions (e.g. uiRouter).

As such, you need to add v. 1.2.22 of `angular-route.js` to your page to continue using `$routeProvider`.

You can either do that with `bower install angular-route` (if you use bower), or download or reference it from [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/)

You will also need to add `ngRoute` as a dependency for `gameApp`:

```
var gameApp = angular.module("gameApp", ['ngRoute']);
```

**Note**: this may happen if you have used other modules that were previously part of the core, the fix is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing some imports. Angualr has been modularized, hence you need to specify which modules you inject to the app.

This is my injection setup for my app (I would guess you miss the 'ngRoute'):

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
        // Angular modules 
        'ngAnimate',        // animations
        'ngRoute',          // routing
        'ngSanitize',       // sanitizes html bindings (ex: sidebar.js)

        // Custom modules 
        'common',           // common functions, logger, spinner
        'common.bootstrap', // bootstrap dialog wrapper functions

        // 3rd Party Modules
        'ui.bootstrap',      // ui-bootstrap (ex: carousel, pagination, dialog)
        'breeze.angular'
    ]);
```